# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, linked-server, openquery

I am trying to query data from linked server. It is giving me the following error:

TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server

Comment: Hi,bro, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are very high that your service name doesn't match a name in your tnsnames.ora file. It's either not registered or registered with a different name.

The following blog post has a really good set of steps to walk you through what to check for it, and for other common causes:

https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-ora-12514-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor/

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same issue while trying to create a linked server from sql server to oracle. I tried multiple ways but it did not work out. But finally, I bounced my server and then tried to create linked server which worked.
Sometimes bouncing the server might solve such issues as that will release any processes that are stuck.

Comment: _I bounced my server_ I wish to know what you mean here.